# KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT not received unless audio is playing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've paired with a Bluetooth headset. When audio is playing, `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS` are received fine in my `BroadcastReceiver`. When audio is not playing, my receiver does not get called for these key events.

In this same state, when audio is not playing, this same receiver is called for play/pause, `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`, so I know this is not an issue of my receiver not being registered.

Once audio does begin to play, I can see via logs that while audio was not playing, all `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT` events were queued, and are re-delivered once audio starts. Each of these events is delivered with KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN.

Is this normal behavior? Do Bluetooth next and previous buttons only function when audio is playing?

Comment: I have no specific experience with it. But I would not be shocked if it were the case that the system only fires events from the bluetooth device while media is being played. Do you have a Log statement that is spitting out data inside onKey()? Perhaps when media is not playing it has a different KEYCODE value.

Comment: No, I receive no broadcast when audio is not playing. I've just confirmed, also, that neither the play or stop command is received when audio isn't playing.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue with one pair of headphones. But when I tried another pair of headphones my *BroadcastReceiver* received  KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS and KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT, when audio was NOT playing. 
So it seems that the issue depends on the headphones you're using.